# Do not show partially visible rows in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I try to implement the following in winform vb net project (I see this work in an app written in delphi).

I wish to hide or set visibility to false of the bottom row that partially visible in dgv that is docked to fill.
I tried to implement something like this:

```
DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.DisplayedRowCount(true) - 1).Visible = False
```

I think it should be called during DataBindingComplete and Resize/scroll events, but it doesn't work.

Do you have any ideas / solutions?

Comment: This would have to be done in the scroll event for sure, so whenever the user scrolls, you have to update which rows are visible. Saying this, I do think that this will slow down the grid alot. Maybe try painting over the partial row instead of hiding every row that is below the partial row

Answer (score 0):

So what I use on one of my datagridviews is:

```
Dim ind As Integer = 0
    ind = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    DataGridView1.Rows(ind).Visible = False
```

which hides the last displayed row of the datagridview.

Answer (score 0):

You requirement sounds somewhat odd. Your comment *”I wish to hide or set visibility to false of the bottom row that partially visible in dgv that is docked to fill.”*... I am curious how you would know this is the last row? Is it not possible that there are more rows below the last one visible? If the scroll bars are available you should see the vertical one if rows go beyond its bounding box. If one of the rows is cut in half by the bounding box and there is more than 1 row below this row, then making invisible/hiding/deleting that row will simply move the next one up.

Since the `DataGridView` is docked you may have to resize the rows manually if you do not want the rows to be split by the bounding box. Another possible solution is to use the `DataGridView`s `AutoSizeRowsMode`  Like below.

```
dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells;
```

This will set the rows so that a row will not be chopped if it is outside the bottom of the bounding box. The rows will auto size to fit evenly There are seven (7) `AutoSizeRowsMode` options and I am guessing one of them may do what you are looking for. I am guessing `DisplayedCells` may work for what you describe. If the grid is re-sized often, you may have to implement this row resizing. Hope this helps.